# Setting specific index in redux state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

That's essentially what I want to do. The problem is this doesn't update state. Any idea what I'm missing?

```
type Tree = Array<Element>;
type SetLayerTreeItem = { payload: Element };

const initialState: Tree = [];

const LayersTree = createSlice({
  name: 'LayersTree',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setLayerTreeItem(state, { payload }: SetLayerTreeItem) {
      state[payload.level] = payload; // Here's the problem
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Can you post how you invoke the action ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli it's this: `dispatch(setLayerTreeItem(currentState));` Where currentState is of correct type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
setLayerTreeItem(state, { payload }: SetLayerTreeItem) {
  const newState = state.slice();
  newState[payload.level] = payload.element;
  return newState;
},
```

Comment: Since createSlice uses [immer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice) (`Internally, it uses createAction and createReducer, so you may also use Immer to write "mutating" immutable updates:`) you don't need to return anything and mutate the draft that you get: `state[payload.level] = payload.element; //do not return anything`

Comment: Yeah, that's the fun part. I can change to null, but changing to another object results in no change. Even with my solution. Any idea why?

Comment: Never mind! The code was correct. I was simply passing the wrong payload ;D